# Use stretchable UIImage in CGContext

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I'm searching a way to draw stretchable image as background of my custom cell background view. I would like to use drawRect method and draw an image stretched exactly as it would be stretched with `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth` in a UIImageView... how can i continue this code to make it happen ?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    UIImage *bgImg =[[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_table_top"]stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:3 topCapHeight:0];

   //How to draw the image stretched as the self.bounds size ? 
....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason not to let UIImageView do this? (Include one as a child of your custom cell.) It's true that reducing child views can be a performance improvement in tables, but UIImageView is also pretty good at getting good performance when drawing images.

My guess is otherwise you're going to have to do multiple draw calls, in order to get the ends and middle drawn correctly.

Comment: I'd like working with drawRect method and within CGContext. Can I use UIImageView in a cleaver way in my case?